# Victoria metrics - metrics associated to a label

Tags: promql, victoriametrics

I need to get all metrics associated to a labels from Victoria Metrics.
Something like:

GET /api/v1/series?match[]=series

but the ability to provide a label selector in the match. Like:

match[]={jobname="abc"}

I need to extract all **name** metrics associated to label {jobname="abc"}

Is it possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
GET /api/v1/label/__name__/values?match[]={jobname="abc"}&start=...&end=...
```

It should return all the metric names with the label `{jobname="abc"}` on the time range `start ... end`. The `start` and `end` args may have the following forms:

- [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in seconds.
- Time relative to the current time. For example, `start=-1h` means `now - 1 hour` timestamp
- [RFC3339 timestamp](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt). For example, `2020-03-15T10:30:59Z`